# Strategic Value of a 720 degree line

Tags: military, strategy, economy, alien-geometry

In this world, there is a line of 720 degrees, as opposed to [Strategic Value of a line of symmetry](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/102378/strategic-value-of-a-line-of-symmetry) which has a line of 180 degrees.

In particular, looking at a cross section of the world, imagine that the world is actually two planes, glued together in such a way that as you move around our line (a point in the cross section), it takes 720 degrees to get around it.

[image]

The green point is a cross section of the 720-degree line. The space is constructed by gluing the two spaces together along the half-plane (called the glue half-plane) coming out of the line of symmetry, A to A and B to B. So if you walk around the line you will go through 360 degrees of each space, for a total of 720 degrees. Another way of explaining it is that it is a branch covering of regular space of degree 2.

Another way to visualize the cross section is a surface with a point with a $-360$ degree angular defect.

My question is, would this line have any (positive or negative) strategic value for a kingdom, if built around it?

Edit: the ground is perpendicular to the line.

Comment: With such geometry, you can arbitrary set that line however you want, as long as you keep the starting point the same, right? So if anything has value, it's the point, not any of infinite possible lines?

Comment: @Mołot I think you misunderstand. The (cross section of the) line is the green point, and is vertical. The glue half-plane (represented by the black line) is the thing that is arbitrary. (Keep in mind that the diagram is just a cross-section.)

Comment: Oh ok, makes sense.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that the "world" is simply twice as big as it should? You could imagine it being built on a partial spiral, 720 degrees in girth. Everything else stays the same.

Comment: @LSerni That's correct. Any region not containing the line would be basically normal.

Comment: \*does some math\* I don't think anyone wants to build here. Its inefficient. You spend double the materials on a wall for double the land instead of $\sqrt{2}$ more materials for double the land.

Comment: @draco18s I think you are correct. I see no compensating upside. I think you should make your comment into an answer of “no strategic benefit”.

Comment: Following @LSerni 's observation - if I'm standing on the ground a few paces from the "point" (where the vertical symmetry line touches the ground), what do I see when I look across it? How things look if I walk around it? - in what way will that look different than just circling any point on Earth? I understand that distances will be skewed, but I'm not clear on how visibility works with this concept.

Comment: @G0BLiN it would look very weird. Basically, you'd see two different nearby places (two places 360 degrees away from each other).

Comment: I expect such a line could have religious significance if not strategic

Answer (score 7):

After having done some math trying to justify the location as valuable I realized it wasn't, no one would want to control this location; its inefficient: The owner would spend double the materials on a wall for double the land instead of $\sqrt{2}$ more materials for double the land everyone else would be subject to, ignoring other concerns (e.g. neighbors, terrain).

Nor does it make it easier to "sneak around behind" enemy lines (it in fact makes it *harder* due to the extra distance needing to be crossed).

## There is no strategic benefit that I can see

Comment: So it would be negative strategic value then, right?

Comment: @PyRulez Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 5):

I don't fully understand the description of your world. I tried to imagine different geometries that fits your description, but all of them doesn't seem to make sense to me. So, this is my best guess:

[image]

There are two planes that are connected with each other, with shared singularity at the center of the two planes. A person needs to walk around the singularity by 720 degree before returning to the same spot. So I think this fits your description?

This geometry has some problems that have to be solved, though:

1. It doesn't seem to be any way for this world to be seamlessly connected to other planes.
2. The outer edge of the world isn't connected to anything, which makes it weird. If someone crosses the edge, is that person just going to float around, disappears, or what?
3. Gravity is the curvature of spacetime. But in this world, the spacetime that connects the upper and lower world is slanted, which is going to create gravitational pull toward the lower word.
4. There's still an overlap between the two planes (between the yellow and the blue). Although the overlap is at one dimension lower, I don't know what chaos it can cause.
5. Singularity at its center.

Solutions:

1. The world is just two cones. One cone can be connected with the "normal" world. The connection is not seamless, and in fact creates another singularity at the intersection of the outer edges between the two planes. But this solves the problem.

   [image]
2. Now it's only the upper world that has unconnected edge. The only solution is to connect it with the existing singularity. This makes the geometry of the upper world shaped like sphere.
3. By introducing more dimensions, you can flatten the geometry, making the two plane stay at the same level in the 3D world. I'm not sure how many dimension you need to add to make it work.
4. The overlap can also be solved by adding more dimensions.
5. My solution is to make the singularity have minimum size, just like how real black hole have event horizon. The difference is that this singularity doesn't have gravitational force.

**Answer:**

[image]

If this is how your world is constructed, any strategic value will depend on the width of the "gate" to the upper plane, and the area of the upper plane.

If the gate is narrow and the upper plane area is large, you can build the kingdom on the upper plane. This makes a great defense since the gate can bottleneck the enemies. The kingdom can even build defensive structures around the gate.

And that's basically it in regards to strategic value. If the gate is too wide and the the upper plane area is too large, the plane just becomes regular plane. The only effect it has is confusion to people who are unfamiliar with the area.

Comment: It goes on forever in all directions. There is no edge.

Comment: Nice drawings, by the way!

Comment: The connection point (where you have the gate) is not discernible from inside the space. The boundary line is just the only way we, poor 3 spatially dimension limited creatures, can understand the space.

Comment: @PyRulez In the 2D world, if both planes are infinite, you still need to have two points at both end of the gate. The gate can't be open-ended unless you want it to extend to the end of the universe. And thanks :)

Comment: @Draco18s The "boundary line" in the 2D world is the singularity itself. In 3D world, the "boundary line" is the edge of the planar, 2D gate (since the gate can't be one dimensional). But there are still a points along the "boundary line" at which the boundary originated. Right?

Comment: @Momok987 The boundary line in 3D space is a line perpendicular to the 2D plane. Just as the 2D entities can't tell which side of the point-singularity we can't tell the difference around the line.

Comment: I think that makes sense when you put it that way

Comment: For example, [this is just as valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kXg0.png). The blue-lined region is a see-through x-ray window to see "under"